# How is the density of a collider determined?

Tags: unity, physics

I read [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BuoyancyEffector2D.html) that, once determining the density of a Buoyancy Effector, "Colliders with a higher density sink, those with a lower density float, and those with the same density appear suspended in the fluid." However, I did not find a density field in my CircleCollider2D. What I found is that:

- If I increase the mass of the attached RigidBody2D, then the body sinks into the fluid - since apparently its density increases.
- If I keep the mass but decrease the size of of the circle collider, then again the body sinks into the fluid - indicating that its density increases.

So my conjecture is that the density is calculated by the mass of the rigid body, divided by the volume of the collider. But I did not find the formula in the Unity manual. Is this correct?

Comment: [this answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/463659/how-does-setdensity-find-volume-and-how-can-i-get.html) would indicate you're correct, and physically density is simply *(mass / volume)* but i would be interested if there was any documentation on this, like how does unity work out the volume of a mesh collider?